# Unable to call Post method using Digest authentication

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to post a method using Digest authentication to a device, but it is not working.

I tried "await client.SendAsync" method but it didn't return reponse , directly closes the application.

I am unable to find issue.

```
private void fnTest()
{ 
var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.12/TestDev");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http:
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            request.Headers.Add("User-Agent",BC "A");

            //var response = await HTTPClientDigestAuth.HttpClientExtensions.SendWithDigestAuthAsync(client, request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, "user", "passord");
            HttpClientExtensionTests();
}
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendWithDigestAuthAsync(this HttpClient client, 
            HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption httpCompletionOption,
            string username, string password)
        {
            var newRequest = CloneBeforeContentSet(request);


            try
            {
             
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)) //--> From this line application closed 
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(response); //-->Not coming to this line

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
                return null;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint within your catch-clause to inspect what the exception says?

Comment: Yes,tried that It says Unauthorized, though login details provided.

Comment: What's the "device"? Do you have access to modify/debug it? If not, how is it documented? The code you posted is currently invalid syntax and doesn't seem to contain any digest (`username` and `password` are not used) - please provide a [mre] with the actual code you have problems with.